# Trying to understand MockSequence

Tags: c#, moq

I'm currently writing an application and to test it's correct behaviour I need to verify that methods are called in a given order.

For my Unit Tests, I'm using [xUnit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit/) and [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/)

Now, why do I need to test the order in which calls are being made?

I'm developing a solution that executes tasks on different threads.
As soon as a task is executed, I'm writing a message to a given logger, so by checking the order in which the calls to the logger are made I'm sure that my code was implemented correctly.

See here the code which I'm trying to use:

```
public class SchedulerFixture
{
    #region Constructors

    public SchedulerFixture()
    {
        LoggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        // Setup of other mocks removed for simplicity.
    }

    #endregion
}

public class SequentialTaskExecutorMock : SchedulerFixture
{
    [Fact]
    public void Should_WriteTheCorrectLogEntries_WhenTasksAreExecutedAndNotCancelled()
    {
        // Defines the task that needs to be executed.
        var task = new LongRunningServiceTaskImplementation();

        // Built a sequence in which logs should be created.
        var sequence = new MockSequence();

        LoggerMock.Setup(x => x.Information(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();

        LoggerMock.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => x.Information("émqsdlfk", "smdlfksdmlfk")).Verifiable();
        LoggerMock.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => x.Information(LoggingResources.LoggerTitle, LoggingResources.Logger_ServiceStopped)).Verifiable();
        LoggerMock.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => x.Information(LoggingResources.LoggerTitle, LoggingResources.Logger_ServiceStarted)).Verifiable();
        LoggerMock.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => x.Information(LoggingResources.LoggerTitle, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, LoggingResources.Logger_TaskCompleted, task.TaskName))).Verifiable();
        LoggerMock.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => x.Information(LoggingResources.LoggerTitle, LoggingResources.Logger_ServiceStopped)).Verifiable();

        // Setup the mock required for the tests.
        TaskGathererMock.Setup(x => x.GetServiceTasks(LoggerMock.Object)).Returns(() =>
        {
            return new[] { task };
        });

        // Start the scheduler.
        Scheduler.Start(TaskGathererMock.Object, ConfigurationManagerMock.Object);

        // Wait for 5 seconds (this simulates running the service for 5 seconds).
        // Since our tasks execution time takes 4 seconds, all the assigned tasks should have been completed.
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        // Stop the service. (We assume that all the tasks have been completed).
        Scheduler.Stop();

        LoggerMock.VerifyAll();
    }
}
```

So, the first step in my test is to setup the logs, then the test itself is executed (this causes calls to the logger) and at the end I'm verifying it.

However, the test does pass always.

It should fail in this case since the following call:

```
LoggerMock.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => x.Information("émqsdlfk", "smdlfksdmlfk")).Verifiable();
```

Is not executed anywhere in my code.

Comment: See [issue #75](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/75), this may be expected behavior.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Great link. But if you look at the thread comments from Jan 2 2014, it is agreed upon that there are two issues (which means Moq "bugs" there). What Complexity experiences in his code above, is their "issue 1".

Comment: Annoying. 4 years later and I have the same problem. Maybe I should update Moq, I'm currently running Moq.4.2.1510.2205. Can anybody confirm that the issue was resolved in a version?

Answer (score 2):

While this sure feels like a bug in Moq (see first comment to the question, by Patrick Quirk), here is a rough idea to what you could do instead. This is sort of a "long comment".

Make a simple class like:

```
class SequenceTracker
{
    int? state;

    public void Next(int newState)
    {
        if (newState <= state)
            Assert.Fail("Bad ordering there! States should be increasing.");

        state = newState;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this (modified version of your own code):

```
public void Should_WriteTheCorrectLogEntries_WhenTasksAreExecutedAndNotCancelled()
{
    // Defines the task that needs to be executed.
    var task = new LongRunningServiceTaskImplementation();

    // USE THE CLASS I PROPOSE:
    var tracker = new SequenceTracker();


    //LoggerMock.Setup(x => x.Information(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))

    LoggerMock.Setup(x => x.Information("émqsdlfk", "smdlfksdmlfk"))
        .Callback(() => tracker.Next(10));
    LoggerMock.Setup(x => x.Information(LoggingResources.LoggerTitle, LoggingResources.Logger_ServiceStopped))
        .Callback(() => tracker.Next(20));
    LoggerMock.Setup(x => x.Information(LoggingResources.LoggerTitle, LoggingResources.Logger_ServiceStarted))
        .Callback(() => tracker.Next(30));
    LoggerMock.Setup(x => x.Information(LoggingResources.LoggerTitle, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, LoggingResources.Logger_TaskCompleted, task.TaskName)))
        .Callback(() => tracker.Next(40));
    LoggerMock.Setup(x => x.Information(LoggingResources.LoggerTitle, LoggingResources.Logger_ServiceStopped))
        .Callback(() => tracker.Next(50));

    // Setup the mock required for the tests.
    TaskGathererMock.Setup(x => x.GetServiceTasks(LoggerMock.Object)).Returns(() =>
    {
        return new[] { task };
    });

    // Start the scheduler.
    Scheduler.Start(TaskGathererMock.Object, ConfigurationManagerMock.Object);

    // Wait for 5 seconds (this simulates running the service for 5 seconds).
    // Since our tasks execution time takes 4 seconds, all the assigned tasks should have been completed.
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    // Stop the service. (We assume that all the tasks have been completed).
    Scheduler.Stop();

    // THIS NOW WORKS BECAUSE WE ABANDONED THE 'MockSequence' APPROACH:
    LoggerMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

Of course this can be made more advanced if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer of Jeppe Stig Nielsen I continued his idea which I think solves your issue somewhat (and which I would prefer to have completed in Moq).
This will verify the complete execution of your mocked sequence:

```
public class SequenceVerifyer
{
    public MockSequence Sequence { get; private set; } = new MockSequence();

    public Action NextCallback()
    {
        var callNo = setupCount++;
        return () => { AssertCallNo(callNo);};
    }
    public void VerifyAll()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(setupCount, executionCount, $"less calls ({executionCount}) executed than previously set up ({setupCount}).");
    }

    private int executionCount = 0;
    private int setupCount = 0;

    private void AssertCallNo(int expectedCallNo)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(executionCount, expectedCallNo, $"order of call is wrong. this call is marked with No ({expectedCallNo}), but ({executionCount}) was expected.");
        executionCount++;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool foo(int n);
}

public interface IBar
{
    int bar(string a);
}

[Test]
public void SequenceVerifyer_with_full_sequence()
{
    var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var barMock = new Mock<IBar>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var seq = new SequenceVerifyer();

    fooMock.Setup(f => f.foo(3)).Returns(false);
    barMock.Setup(b => b.bar("world")).Returns(4);

    fooMock.InSequence(seq.Sequence).Setup(f => f.foo(4)).Returns(true).Callback(seq.NextCallback());
    barMock.InSequence(seq.Sequence).Setup(b => b.bar("hello")).Returns(2).Callback(seq.NextCallback());
    fooMock.InSequence(seq.Sequence).Setup(f => f.foo(4)).Returns(false).Callback(seq.NextCallback());

    fooMock.Object.foo(3); //non sequence
    fooMock.Object.foo(4);
    barMock.Object.bar("hello");
    barMock.Object.bar("world"); //non sequence
    fooMock.Object.foo(4);

    fooMock.VerifyAll();
    barMock.VerifyAll();
    seq.VerifyAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53758402/1830814)

## Usage

```
            void Test()
            {
                // Arrange
                var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
                using var seq = SequenceVerifier.For(fooMock);

                seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(1), true);
                seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(2), false);

                // Act
                fooMock.Object.Foo(1);
                fooMock.Object.Foo(2);
            }
```

## Implementation

```
#nullable enable
using FluentAssertions;
using Moq;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tests.Core
{
    public abstract class SequenceVerifier : IDisposable
    {
        public static SequenceVerifier<T> For<T>(Mock<T> mock)
            where T : class
        {
            return new SequenceVerifier<T>(mock);
        }

        public void Dispose() => Dispose(true);
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) { }
    }

    public sealed class SequenceVerifier<T> : SequenceVerifier
        where T : class
    {
        private int expectedCalls;
        private int actualCalls;
        public readonly MockSequence Sequence = new MockSequence();

        public Mock<T> Mock { get; }

        public SequenceVerifier(Mock<T> mock)
        {
            Mock = mock ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mock));
            if (Mock.Behavior != MockBehavior.Strict)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(MockBehavior)} must be {nameof(MockBehavior.Strict)}");
            }
        }

        public Action NextCallback()
        {
            int currentCall = expectedCalls++;
            return () => AssertCallNo(currentCall);
        }

        public void VerifyAll()
        {
            actualCalls.Should().Be(expectedCalls, $"the number of actual calls must be the same as previously set up");
        }

        private void AssertCallNo(int expectedCallNo)
        {
            actualCalls.Should().Be(expectedCallNo, $"calls must be in order");
            actualCalls++;
        }

        public void Setup<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult?>> expression, TResult? result = default)
        {
            if (typeof(TResult) == typeof(Task) && result is null)
            {
                result = (TResult)(object)Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            Mock.InSequence(Sequence)
                .Setup(expression)
                .Returns(result)
                .Callback(NextCallback());
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) 
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Mock.VerifyAll();
                VerifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Unit Tests

```
#nullable enable
using static FluentAssertions.FluentActions;
using Moq;
using Xunit;
using FluentAssertions;
using System;

namespace Tests.Core
{
    public class SequenceVerifierFixture
    {
        public interface IFoo
        {
            bool Foo(int n);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Given2SetupsAndNonSequenceSetup_When2CallsInOrderAndNonSequenceCall_ThenVerificationSuccessful()
        {
            var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            var seq = SequenceVerifier.For(fooMock);

            fooMock.Setup(f => f.Foo(3)).Returns(false);

            seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(4), true);
            seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(4), false);

            fooMock.Object.Foo(3); //non sequence
            fooMock.Object.Foo(4);
            fooMock.Object.Foo(4);

            fooMock.VerifyAll();
            seq.VerifyAll();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Given2Setups_WhenCallOnly1stSetupThenDispose_ThenVerificationFails()
        {
            // Arrange
            var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            var seq = SequenceVerifier.For(fooMock);

            seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(1), true);
            seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(2), false);

            // Act
            fooMock.Object.Foo(1);

            // Assert
            Invoking(seq.Dispose)
                .Should().Throw<Exception>();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Given2Setups_WhenCallOnly1stSetupWithinUsing_ThenVerificationFails()
        {
            void WithinUsing()
            {
                // Arrange
                var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
                using var seq = SequenceVerifier.For(fooMock);

                seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(1), true);
                seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(2), false);

                // Act
                fooMock.Object.Foo(1);
            }

            // Assert
            Invoking(WithinUsing)
                .Should().Throw<Exception>();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Given2Setups_WhenCall2SetupsThenExtraCall_ThenVerificationFails()
        {
            // Arrange
            var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            var seq = SequenceVerifier.For(fooMock);

            seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(1), true);
            seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(2), false);

            // Act
            fooMock.Object.Foo(1);
            fooMock.Object.Foo(2);

            // Assert
            Invoking(() => fooMock.Object.Foo(1))
                .Should().Throw<Exception>();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Given2Setups_WhenCallSetup1Twice_ThenVerificationFails()
        {
            // Arrange
            var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            var seq = SequenceVerifier.For(fooMock);

            seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(1), true);
            seq.Setup(f => f.Foo(2), false);

            // Act
            fooMock.Object.Foo(1);

            // Assert
            Invoking(() => fooMock.Object.Foo(1))
                .Should().Throw<Exception>();
        }
    }
}
```